# How to create Rain Effect in surfaceView?

Tags: java, android, effect

I'm trying to create a rain effect in android. I have already created the sprite class, what I don't know is how to do that appear X amount of drops per second or the time of life. Can somebody help me?

Thanks.

This is my code

Sprite class:

```
public class Sprite_Rain {

private Bitmap rain_drop;
private Game game;
private int speed = 50;
int x, y = -100;
boolean position = true;
Paint paint;

public Sprite_Rain(Game game, Bitmap rain_drop){

    this.game = game;
    this.rain_drop= rain_drop;

    paint = new Paint();
}

public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    if (position == true) {
        Random random = new Random();
        x = random.nextInt(canvas.getWidth());
        position = false;
    }

    canvas.drawBitmap(rain_drop, x, y, null);
}
}
```

Game class:

```
public class Game extends SurfaceView {

private Bitmap rain_drop;
private Sprite_Rain sprite_rain;
Paint paint;

private List<Sprite_Rain> sprites = new ArrayList<Sprite_Rain>();

public Game(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    rain_drop = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.rain_drop);
    sprite_rain = new Sprite_Rain(this, rain_drop);

    paint = new Paint();
}

private Sprite_Rain createSprite(int resource) {
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resource);
    return new Sprite_Rain(this, bmp);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    int i = 0;
    for (Sprite_Rain sprite : sprites) {
        sprite.onDraw(canvas);
        i++;
    }
    invalidate();
}
}
```